# Carousel indexing

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

So I am making a carousel and I encountered and issue that I cant figure out.

With the first iteration it does work wonders but alas the outindexing is not handled.
I figured it would be easy: Turns out it is not.

I get undefined in place of the carousel when I try to add logic to it. Anybody has a tip where I messed up?
Thank you in advance.

That works but has no outindexing protection.

```js
const $leftButton = document.querySelector("#LEFT_BUTTON");
const $rightButton = document.querySelector("#RIGHT_BUTTON");

const CarouselList = [
  '<a href="http://"><img src="Images/Vector_2677.jpg" alt="1"></a>',
  '<a href="http://"><img src="Images/Vector_2677.jpg" alt="2"></a>',
  '<a href="http://"><img src="Images/Vector_2677.jpg" alt="3"></a>',
  '<a href="http://"><img src="Images/Vector_2677.jpg" alt="4"></a>',
  '<a href="http://"><img src="Images/Vector_2677.jpg" alt="5"></a>',
];

let CarouselListCurrentPosition = 0;

$leftButton.addEventListener("click", leftClick);

function leftClick() {
  document.querySelector("#CAROUSEL_ELEMENTS").innerHTML =
    CarouselList[CarouselListCurrentPosition - 1];
  CarouselListCurrentPosition = CarouselListCurrentPosition - 1;
}

$rightButton.addEventListener("click", rightClick);

function rightClick() {
  document.querySelector("#CAROUSEL_ELEMENTS").innerHTML =
    CarouselList[CarouselListCurrentPosition + 1];
  CarouselListCurrentPosition = CarouselListCurrentPosition + 1;
}
```

And my issue to my best knowledge it should work but it does not.

```js
function leftClick() {
  if (CarouselListCurrentPosition === 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#CAROUSEL_ELEMENTS").innerHTML =
      CarouselList[CarouselListCurrentPosition - 1];
    CarouselListCurrentPosition = CarouselListCurrentPosition - 1;
  }
}

$rightButton.addEventListener("click", rightClick);

function rightClick() {
  if (CarouselListCurrentPosition === 4) {
    return;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#CAROUSEL_ELEMENTS").innerHTML =
      CarouselList[CarouselListCurrentPosition - 1];
    CarouselListCurrentPosition = CarouselListCurrentPosition - 1;
  }
}
```